# How to change iter the change of value to centre while maintaining the list of 20 values in Python

Tags: python

```
list = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100.2,112.3,132.3,133.5,134.5,136.2,136.3,138.3,138.5,139.5]
```

I want to add value '0' at the first few indexes to make the rising value (0 to 100.2) to be in the middle, for example, the length of list is 20 I trying to make the rise value at 10th place by removing the equal amount of value add from the last 2 indexes from the back of the list so that the original value of 20 will also have the same amount of 20 value as output

After Centralized the list output:

> > list = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100.2,112.3,132.3,133.5,134.5,136.2,136.3,138.3,138.5,139.5]

I have solve the problem to this solution.The answer i that i came out with as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Dec 13 17:09:59 2019

@author: lzh
"""
from collections import Counter

orig = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100.2,112.3,132.3,133.5,134.5,136.2,136.3,138.3]

ad = []

c=Counter(orig)

c.values()
print(c.values())
cs = list(c.values())

if cs[0] < 10:
    mod = (10 - cs[0])*[0] + (orig)

    for i in range((10 - cs[0])):

        mod.pop()

if cs[0] > 10:

    for x in range((cs[0] - 10)):
        ad.append(orig[-1])
    mod = (orig) + (ad)
    for i in range((cs[0]-10)):
        del mod[0]

#modified = ([0] * (20 - len(orig))) + (orig)
print(mod)
```

Comment: what­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: I don't understand the logic... do you want to add two `0`s to the list?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I guess so :)

Answer (score 1):

To extend to a certain size, reverse the list, pad with the value you want, and reverse the list again:

```
mylist=list
mylist.reverse() 
mylist.extend([0] * (20 - len(mylist)))
mylist.reverse() 

# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100.2, 112.3, 132.3, 133.5, 134.5, 136.2, 136.3, 138.3, 138.5, 139.5]
```

also 'list' is a reserved keyword, so i set this to a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `list` variable to `orig` and `modified`

> orig =
>   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100.2,112.3,132.3,133.5,134.5,136.2,136.3,138.3,138.5,139.5]

```
modified = ([0] * (20 - len(orig))) + (orig)
```

Explanation:

- `[0] * n` gives an array of `n` zeroes
- `20 - len(orig)` gives number of zeroes less than 20 in the `orig` array.
- `[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]` will concatenate the two arrays, giving `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Answer (score 0):

You could also ask `numpy` to handle this task.

Assuming you have a fixed length of 20 you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

np.pad(lists, (20-len(lists),0), 'constant', constant_values=0)
```

Explanation:

`np.pad` will add a constant, in this case `0` to the left of your array to ensure a length of 20 (`20-len(lists)`).

Output:

```
array([  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,
         0. , 100.2, 112.3, 132.3, 133.5, 134.5, 136.2, 136.3, 138.3,
       138.5, 139.5])
```